# Same code on multiple pages, way to create a template file and include in all pages?

Tags: php, html

I have a header that will be on every page of my site and instead of adding the `html`/`php` to each page I was thinking I could just make a template file and include it with a php `include()` so it's easier to modify if I have to change something. Is there a better way to do this and would using the `PHP` include slow down my site? Thanks in advance.

Comment: is this a bare-bones PHP or are you using a framework of sorts? What you have described is exactly what PHP `include` and `require` are for.

Comment: Barebone php. Would using `include` / `require` slow down my performance in any way?

Comment: Including headers, footers and other static contents on all pages that will have the same content is generally a good idea, it's easier to maintain and update. You might want to take a look at [this StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2418514/4535200).

Comment: @JoeScotto Depends how many files are you including, your other option is Server Side Includes (on Apache), other servers may have their own implementation. See this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993858/ssi-or-php-include

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**you can use include/require() but please reamember that same file doesn't include twice otherwise it will conflict.You can declare variable globaly so that it provide you easy way.**